# Error code -36 when copying files to external hard drive

Tags: finder, hard-drive, external-disk, spotlight, error

Each time I attempt to copy files to a particular HDD, I get the following message:

> The Finder can’t complete the operation because some data in
> “filename.extension” can’t be read or written.
> (Error code -36)

Meanwhile, attempts to duplicate any file on the device result in a "nameless" version of the above:

> The Finder can’t complete the operation because some data in “” can’t
> be read or written. (Error code -36)

The problem doesn't appear to be the files, as the same happens with any and all files that I've tried to copy to this HDD; indeed, all of the various files I've tested are fully functional and can be readily copied to other external devices.

Rather, the problem seems to be how this particular HDD is "interpreting" any new file it receives or encounters.

As for the files already on the device, although I can open/view/play any of them, rename them, move them to different folders and drag them successfully to my desktop (where they all function perfectly normally), I cannot make duplicates or save changes to any of them while they remain on the HDD. I am, however, able to delete any such files.

Now, from my research, it seems that `dot_clean` often comes up as a go-to fix for "Error code -36". So I tried the following in Terminal, but without success:

- `sudo dot_clean /Volumes/Backup`
- `sudo dot_clean -m /Volumes/Backup`
- `sudo dot_clean -mn /Volumes/Backup`

I also tried targeting ".Trashes" directly with this sequence:

1. `cd /Volumes/Backup`
2. `cd .Trashes`
3. `sudo ls -a` (which outputted: `.   ..  501`)
4. `sudo dot_clean .Trashes`

But no luck there either.

Additionally, this HDD had been causing Finder to freeze up when viewing "Get Info" or using the Inspector, necessitating a Finder relaunch each time. This was resolved after adding the device to the list under **System Preferences > Spotlight > Privacy** (which was only possible after first force-quitting the process "mds" in Activity Monitor).

Interestingly, that particular issue no longer occurs even after undoing the above Spotlight tweak (so maybe it was the force quit just prior?), but this minor triumph aside, the problem with "Error code -36" still persists...

Does anybody know what the cause might be?

Comment: What format is the drive? Can you get the response to `diskutil list` in Terminal.

Comment: Hi @Tetsujin. The drive uses a GUID Partition Map and the file system format is Mac OS Extended (Journaled). The response to `diskutil list` looks totally normal, with `GUID_partition_scheme`, `EFI` and `Apple_HFS` respectively listed in the `TYPE` column.

Comment: See if you can get SMART data for it [might depend on how it's connected] &/or copy all the data off & re-format. It might be the drive or it might be its connectivity, intermittent. Could maybe shuck the drive from the case & try another adapter.

Comment: In Disk Utility it says "S.M.A.R.T. Status: Not Supported". My working HDD (of the same type) says the same thing too, so I think that's just how it is. Would connectivity problems necessarily be obvious (e.g. ejecting frequently)?

Comment: Fully ejecting itself would be well on the way to total failure, but very short, intermittent problems may not show up so easily - other than in the read/write errors you're seeing. You won't know without shucking the drive whether it's the drive itself or the enclosure. [Many USB devices don't support SMART, so it's not completely surprising. Here where I have Mac Pros, I'd mount one internally to test for that.]

Comment: I just (belatedly?) thought I'd run `diskutil verifyVolume /dev/disk2s2` and after a normal-looking first four lines came the following: `Keys out of order`, `The volume Backup was found corrupt and needs to be repaired`, `File system check exit code is 8`, `Error: -69610: Error parsing fsck program XML format output` and `Underlying error: 8: Exec format error`. Does this point to another kind of problem? (i.e. would it still be worth shucking the drive?)

Comment: I'd try a format & retest, but next step would be get the drive out of the enclosure, yeah I think.

Comment: Formatting would erase the data would it not? This would probably be the most straightforward solution, but unfortunately I don't have spare storage to first copy the data onto.

Comment: Cheaper to have a spare drive than lose the data if that one dies completely… ;)

Comment: The "buy a new/extra one" route might be the most logical one after all. But I always liked the idea of "finding a way". A bit too idealistic? It does feel like I'm quickly moving towards the first option...

Comment: Wow. So I'd been holding off, but I just ran "First Aid" in Disk Utility; the process failed and the drive is now read-only. How normal is this kind of outcome? Was I indeed right to be cautious about running "First Aid"?

Comment: Either the drive or the enclosure is dying… and fast. Time for that new drive, while you still can.

Comment: Well @Tetsujin, you leave me in no doubt about the common-sense option! I won't plug this one in until I'm ready with a replacement in my hand. After that, we'll see whether the affected drive can actually be erased/formatted back to health – it might be worth having this as part of an answer.